# How to convert range of generated alphanumeric code into an array

Tags: php, arrays, alphanumeric

```
 The below code is what I have written
<?php
 $pincode="" ;
function getPinCode($length){
 $pincode = "";
 $codeAlphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
 $codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";

 $max = strlen($codeAlphabet); // edited
 for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $pincode.= $codeAlphabet[random_int(0, $max-1)];//to output the combined code
 implode('', $pincode)// to convert the code to array
 $pincode= array()//explicitly declare $pincode var
 }
​return $pincode;
 }

for ($n=0;$n<8; $n++){
echo getPinCode(11);
echo ", ";
print_r($pincode);
}?>
```

//If I run the above it gives errors
     1. Array to string conversion
     2. Implode() invalid argument passed.
     If I comment on those two lines where the errors           /originate it generates 8 different codes but not as an     array.

I want to do is to generate a set of codes /using php and make them into an array. Please     where     exactly did I go wrong. Thanks a million
​

Comment: post the desired result

Comment: Am a beginner and self taught so please let your explanation be explicit for one of my kind, thanks

Comment: Am a beginner and self taught so please let your explanation be explicit for one of my kind, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could simply assign to a $pincode  array the random values

```
for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
   $pincode[$i]= $codeAlphabet[random_int(0, $max-1)];//array of the code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 implode('', $pincode)// to convert the code to array
 $pincode= array()//explicitly declare $pincode var
```

You're not assigning the return value of implode then you're just creating an empty array for $pincode.

Comment: Please how do I go about this, I mean assigning the value of implode?

Comment: `$var = 'something';` is called assigning `$var` to `'something'`.  In other words, you aren't setting anything equal to the implode().